# Check if all rows are the same in a matrix

Tags: r

I'm looking to see if `sample(..., replace=T)` results in sampling the same row `n` times. I see the `duplicated` function checks if elements are repeated by returning a logical vector for each index, but I need to see if one element is repeated `n` times (single boolean value). What's the best way to go about this?

Here's just an example. Some function on this matrix should return `TRUE`

```
t(matrix(c(rep(c(rep(4,1),rep(5,1)),8)),nrow=2,ncol=8))
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    4    5
[2,]    4    5
[3,]    4    5
[4,]    4    5
[5,]    4    5
[6,]    4    5
[7,]    4    5
[8,]    4    5
```

Comment: Have you tried `table`? Also, can you post example input, expected output so we can help with working code?

Comment: No, what can `table` do?

Comment: Try `?table` at R console and it should provide details.

Comment: Ahhh. I see. This helps a lot. Think I got it, will update.

Comment: Saving your matrix as `m` for example and running `table(m)` show that each value is repeated 8 times. Alternatively, you can use `apply(m, 2, function(x) length(unique(x)) == 1)` to see if same value is repeated in entire column. Depending on your desired output, these or some other options would be useful.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here is one solution that works to produce the true/false result you are looking for:

```
m <- t(matrix(c(rep(c(rep(4,1),rep(5,1)),8)),nrow=2,ncol=8))
apply(m, 2, function(x) length(unique(x)) == 1)
[1] TRUE TRUE

m <- rbind(m, c(4, 6))
apply(m, 2, function(x) length(unique(x)) == 1)
[1]  TRUE FALSE
```

If you want a single boolean value saying if all columns have unique values, you can do:

```
all(apply(m, 2, function(x) length(unique(x)) == 1) == TRUE)
[1] FALSE
```

Comment: If matrix/data.frame has missing value, `all(apply(A, 1, function(x) length(unique(x[!is.na(x)]))))`  will ignore NAs before checking unique values. More at https://stackoverflow.com/a/2269182/1243763

Comment: For getting a single boolean you can get rid of the `== TRUE` at the end

Answer (score 1):

A little cleaner looking (and easier to tell what the code is doing):

```
m <- t(matrix(c(rep(c(rep(4,1),rep(5,1)),8)),nrow=2,ncol=8))
apply(m, 2, function(x) all(x==x[1]))
[1] TRUE TRUE
```

Answer (score 0):

Think I've got my solution.

```
B <- t(matrix(c(rep(c(rep(4,1),rep(5,1)),8)),nrow=2,ncol=8))
length(table(B)) == ncol(B)
[1] TRUE
B <- rbind(B,c(4,6)) # different sample
length(table(B)) == ncol(B)
[1] FALSE
```

Comment: While it does, you probably are better off using `apply(m, 2, function(x) length(unique(x)) == 1)` as it will tell you specifically if a column has more than one value.

Answer (score 0):

We could also replicate the first row, compare with the original matrix, get the `colSums` and check whether it is equal to `nrow` of 'm'

```
colSums(m[1,][col(m)]==m)==nrow(m)
[1] TRUE TRUE
```

Or another option would be to check the variance

```
!apply(m, 2, var)
#[1] TRUE TRUE
```

Answer (score 0):

For a matrix you can apply `unique` directly to your matrix, no need for `apply`:

```
nrow(unique(m)) == 1L
[1] TRUE
```

```
nrow(unique(rbind(m, c(6,7)))) == 1L
[1] FALSE
```

From the documentation `?unique`:

> The array method calculates for each element of the dimension specified by MARGIN if the remaining dimensions are identical to those for an earlier element (in row-major order). This would most commonly be used for matrices to find unique rows (the default) or columns (with MARGIN = 2).

---

Alternatively you can transpose your matrix and leverage vectorized comparison:

```
all(m[1,] == t(m))
[1] TRUE
```