# How to remove non-informative columns with and without missing values in dataframe

Tags: r

I have a large dataset that looks like this:

```
M1 = c("A", "A", "A")
M2 = c("C", "G", "C")
M3 = c("T", "", "T")
M4 = c("G", "G", "G/C")
M5 = c("T", "T/C", "")
mydata = data.frame(M1, M2, M3, M4, M5)
mydata
```

What I want to do is remove columns that have the same character in each row such as M1 and M3, which has a missing value, too. 
I have managed to remove the "M1" columns in my dataset, with the command "drop_noninformative_columns(x)" in dyrt,  but struggle to remove the "M3" columns that have missing values in them without deleting all columns with missing values.

If anyone could give me some ideas that would be great!

Thanks!

Comment: "NA" is not a missing value in R. Try `NA` or `NA_character_`. After that, there's `length(unique(na.omit(x))) == 1L` that can be applied to each column, as seen here http://stackoverflow.com/a/2269272/ .

Comment: my bad, I meant either "NA" or "", I couldn't manage it in either scenario

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Frank alluded to, you can use `unique` and `apply` to find which columns do not have informative values. In your case, you would need to first convert all the empty values and any hardcoded "NA" values to NA.

```
mydata[mydata == ""] <- NA
mydata[mydata == "NA"] <- NA
```

Then you can use this to filter the original dataframe and only keep columns that have more than one unique value:

```
mydata2 <- mydata[, apply(mydata, 2,function(x) length(unique(na.omit(x)))) > 1]
```

Comment: Thanks to you both that was what I needed, there are still a few columns I need to edit by hand but this has made it much easier to deal with it!

Comment: @Sumitt please accept the answer if it helps, thanks!