# Remove columns in R based on the values of the first two rows

Tags: r

I have big data set that looks like this (actually it's got thousands of columns):
[image]

Or

```
A = c("AA","AA","AA","AA","AA")
B = c("CC","GG","CC","CG","GG")
C = c("TT","AA","AA","AT","TT")
D = c("GG","GG","GG","GG","GG")
E = c("TT","TT","NA","TT","TT")

mydata = data.frame(A, B, C, D, E)
mydata
```

Basically I would like to do 2 things:

1. Remove the columns from the data set, in where the value of the first and second row (within the column) is the same, so in this case, columns "A", "D", and "E" would be excluded.
2. Change the names of the cells referred to the values in the first and second row (within a column): If the cell has the same value as the cellin row 1 would be called "f", and if is same as row 2 "m"; and otherwise "h".

This is the table I would like to obtain in the end:

```
B = c("CC","GG","f","h","m")
C = c("TT","AA","m","h","f")

mydata = data.frame(B, C)
mydata
```

For the first point I've managed to get similiar results by using an apply function as in [How to remove non-informative columns with and without missing values in dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44026926/how-to-remove-non-informative-columns-with-and-without-missing-values-in-datafra), but what I would like is to reffer the condition to certain cells, like when using an "if" function in Excel.

I would appreciate any ideas of types of functions to use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First thing you need to make is that your strings are characters instead of factors:

```
A = c("AA","AA","AA","AA","AA")
B = c("CC","GG","CC","CG","GG")
C = c("TT","AA","AA","AT","TT")
D = c("GG","GG","GG","GG","GG")
E = c("TT","TT","NA","TT","TT")

mydata = data.frame(A, B, C, D, E,stringsAsFactors = F)
```

Then for your first step you can do something like this:

```
mydata2<-mydata[,!mydata[1,]==mydata[2,]]
mydata2
```

and for your second step:

```
mydata2[-c(1:2),]<-lapply(mydata2,function(x)
            ifelse(x[-c(1,2)]==x[1],'f',
                   ifelse(x[-c(1,2)]==x[2],'m','h'))
)

> mydata2
   B  C
1 CC TT
2 GG AA
3  f  m
4  h  h
5  m  f
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, It´s useful and the last command works fine. I get an error in the command for the first step: "Error in `[.data.frame`(mydata2, , !mydata2[1, ] == mydata2[2, ]) : 
  undefined columns selected"  I´ve tried to add a comma to define the columns, which does not give nay error, but does not change the data. I wonder if this is because the dataframe I´m using is different (the data is a table with thousands of columns, so not like in the example)

Comment: I think here `[.data.frame(mydata2, , !mydata2[1, ] == mydata2[2, ]) ` you are using a data frame that doesn't exist yet. you be using `mydata` in to make that comparison and not `mydata2`